# react not updating array state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

if I clicked the button to update name then it's not changing using setState I want update persons variable and as well it should update in the DOM.

Please suggest me idea how to update the state

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Person from "./component/Person";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      persons: [
        { name: "max", age: 28 },
        { name: "manu", age: 29 },
        { name: "step", age: 26 }
      ]
    };
  }

  chnagenames = () => {
    console.log("clicked me ");
    this.setState = {
      persons: [
        { name: "maxi", age: 28 },
        { name: "manr", age: 29 },
        { name: "step", age: 27 }
      ]
    };
    console.log(this.state.persons);
  };

  render() {
    return <> {/* ... */} </>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Person.js

```
import React from "react";

const Person = props => {
  return (
    <>
      person age is {props.ages} and name is {props.attrib}{" "}
    </>
  );
};

export default Person;
```

Comment: It seems you could have a typo: `chnagenames`. Is `clicked me` logged in the console?

Answer (score 1):

You should call `this.setState` as it is a function, not assign a new value to it.

You also have a typo on the `chnagenames` method, and `setState` is also asynchronous so you will not see the change if you log it directly after `setState`.

```
changenames = () => {
  console.log("clicked me ");
  this.setState(
    {
      persons: [
        { name: "maxi", age: 28 },
        { name: "manr", age: 29 },
        { name: "step", age: 27 }
      ]
    },
    () => console.log(this.state.persons)
  );
};
```

Comment: @SakibMulla You're welcome! Consider [accepting one of the answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) if you feel any of them answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

***please try this :***

```
chnagenames = () => {
    console.log("clicked me ");
    var changedArray = [
        { name: "maxi", age: 28 },
        { name: "manr", age: 29 },
        { name: "step", age: 27 }
      ];

    this.setState({
      persons: changedArray
    }, function {
      console.log(this.state.persons);});    
  };
```